# How to receive Intent when USB Accessory is attached if application is already running

Tags: android, android-intent, android-usb

I was able to read up [here](http://jeffreysambells.com/2011/05/15/identifying-your-android-usb-accessory) about how to launch my app when a USB accessory is attached, and that much all works fine:  I have an IntentFilter built into my manifest which will launch the appropriate activity each time the specified accessory is attached.  Here is how that looks:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
</activity>
```

However, I am having issues if my Activity is already running when the accessory is attached.  Within MainActivity, I look for the USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED Intent in two places: onCreate, and onNewIntent, like so:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Check for some other actions first
    if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED.equals(intent.getAction()))
        usbAttached(intent);

}
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED.equals(intent.getAction()))
        usbAttached(intent);
}
```

However, neither onCreate nor onNewIntent is being called when the accessory is plugged in if MainActivity is already running.  In that case, I need to close my app before plugging in the accessory, which would be a hassle for users.  What would be the appropriate way to receive the Intent from my USB accessory if my activity is already running?  Would I need to implement a separate listener within the activity itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of `onNewIntent()` it reads:

> **protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent)**
>
> Added in API level 1
>   This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch it.
>   ...

So you need to set the `launchMode` of your `Activity` to `singleTop` in your manifest, otherwise you will receive no calls to `onNewIntent()`. The result should look something like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:exported="true">
           ... 
</activity>
```

If you think about it that behavior actually makes a lot of sense. Next time look at the documentation before asking here. Don't assume how stuff works if you don't know.

Comment: This works, but I used singleTop (per the documentation) instead of singleInstance  (per the example).  singleInstance did receive the Intent as well, though.

Comment: @user3174484 of course.  I mixed up singleTop and singleInstance when writing the example! Glad I could help you!

Answer (score -1):

Write a `BroadcastReceiver` and register it in one your activity lifecycle methods via [`Context.registerReceiver(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29).  Don't forget to unregister it in the corresponding teardown lifecycle method.

Comment: This answer suggests a completely wrong approach to this problem.

Comment: @XaverKapeller is right; this will not work for reasons that are widely considered a bug.  If it's not a bug in Android, then it's at least a bug in the documentation, which implies that this *should* work.